# Curvature of a plane given a circumference

Tags: geometry

I was skimming through a certain book when I came to an interesting passage.

> And he made a molten sea, ten cubits from the one brim to the other: it was round all about, and his height was five cubits: and a line of thirty cubits did compass it round about.

On a flat plane, 10π≠30, so what radius of a globe would you need to have so that a diameter of 10 creates a circumference of 30?

Comment: sorry, misread part of the quote -- skip this

Comment: This "certain book" uses $ \ \pi = 3 \ $ in a number of places (although better approximations were known elsewhere in those times).  So there likely isn't any non-Euclidean geometry being described here...

Comment: When all the numbers are "nice" ($5$, $10$, $30$), probably they are intended to be only rough approximations.

Comment: I understand that π=3 was an approximation in this case, I was just wondering under what circumstances it would π=3.

Comment: Hah!  Not often that you see a math problem from 1 Kings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $\alpha$ to be the (half) angle of a cone with apex at the center of the globe, and intersects the globe with a circle.

The relation between the diameter $d$ (arc distance) across this circle, the globe radius $r$, and $\alpha$ is $2 \alpha r = d.$

The relation describing the circumference of the circle is $2 \pi r \sin \alpha = 3d.$

Ten cubits is, let's say, $4.572$ meters (according to Google). So

$$r \alpha = 2.286 m; r \sin \alpha = 2.18296m.$$

The value of $\alpha$ that allows these equations to be consistent is around $0.5236$ radians, which means that the radius of the globe would need to be about $4.36 m$.

So, this gives strong evidence that $\pi \approx 3$ was used, rather than careful non-Euclidean geometry.

Comment: The circumference-to-"diameter" ratio on a spherical surface works the same on a sphere of any radius.  Your expressions are correct, but the ratio is $$ \ \Pi \ = \frac{2 \pi R \sin \alpha

Comment: (Sorry, timed out while I was calculating and editing.)  The circumference-to-"diameter" ratio on a spherical surface works the same on a sphere of any radius.  Your expressions are correct, but the ratio is $$ \ \Pi \ = \ \frac{2 \pi R \sin \alpha }{2 R \alpha} \ = \ \pi \ \cdot \frac{\sin \alpha}{\alpha} \ . $$  So the ratio gives $ \ \Pi \ = \ 3 \ $ for $ \ \frac{\sin \alpha}{\alpha} \ = \  \ \frac{3}{\pi} \ \Rightarrow \ \alpha \ \approx \ 0.524 \ \text{rad.} \ \approx \ 30º \ . $

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that there is an implied numerical error when the figures are given.  So the diameter could be anything between 9.5 and 10.5, and the circumference between 29.5 and 30.5.  This gives $2.81 \le \pi \le 3.21$.  Remember, the document isn't trying to define $\pi$ - rather it is recording distances.